# How to make a non-conductive filled via in EAGLE PCB

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, via

How do I make a via that is filled with a non-conductive material in EAGLE PCB?

Comment: You want to fill just one via? Or all the vias? Or all the vias less than a certain diameter?

Comment: Draw dot in text layer directly top on (or bottom) via. This is not the same like epoxy resin but sometimes work well good.

Answer (score 1):

Your CAD tool doesn't have to really know anything about which vias are filled.

You can just add an instruction to your fab drawing, for example:

> Fill all vias less than .35 mm diameter with nonconductive epoxy.

or

> Fill all vias in designated region "A" with nonconductive epoxy [accompanied by a call-out in the drawing to region "A"].

or

> Vias specified as 0.251 mm diameter to be drilled as 0.25 mm and filled with nonconductive epoxy

If you also want these vias plated over, you should add something like "...and plate over with minimum 18 um copper" after any of these instructions.

If in doubt, ask your fab shop about their capabilities and the preferred wording of such instructions.